# Ionic:Vertical scroll not working after adding HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, hammer.js

i am using `"@ionic/angular": "5.0.7"` and
i am trying to use `import { LongPressModule } from 'ionic-long-press';` and using provider with hammergestureconfig `{ provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: IonicGestureConfig }` for ngx-datable.
but after adding gesture config vertical scroll is not working.

**IonicGestureConfig.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { HammerGestureConfig } from '@angular/platform-browser'

/**
 * @hidden
 * This class overrides the default Angular gesture config.
 */
@Injectable()
export class IonicGestureConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
  buildHammer(element: HTMLElement) {
    if (window) {
      const mc = new (<any>window).Hammer(element);        
      for (const eventName in this.overrides) {
        if (eventName) {
          mc.get(eventName).set(this.overrides[eventName])
        }
      }
      return mc;
    }
  }
}


<datatable-row-wrapper 
          ...
          ion-long-press 
          [interval]="500" 
          (pressed)="pressed($event, group, getRowIndex(group && group[i]))" 
          (longPressed)="onLongPressStart($event, group, getRowIndex(group && group[i]))"
        >
```

how to solve this vertical scroll not working issue?